# GennyMotion virtual device can't boot, cannot test Android program

Tags: java, android, android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm trying to develop **Android Application** for personal development. I'm a newbie and I don't have any android devices, so I'm using an Android **emulator**. I've tried to use **BlueStacks** that didn't work (and asked me to pay after one day), and I'm now using **GenyMotion**. I'm trying to develop Android Application on a HP computer, Windows 10 OS, with 6GB RAM and an AMD Processor.

Here is my Android App, which is a very simple one, to test an emulator :

```
package My.Package;

import android.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
        text1.setText("Hello World");
        setContentView(text1);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I launch AVD that I created threw the AVD Manager, the emulator gets stuck on the "android" screen for hours. I have an AMD processor, and not an **Intel** processor.

I've tried **GenyMotion**, but when I launch the device I created with, the device is created but not launched.

I've looked in **VirtualBox** and tried to launch it from Virtual Box, but I have the following error :

[image: ERROR]

I've search on internet for a while, and I've found an answer about modifying the **BIOS** configuration, and to set the Virtualized Technology Active, which I did. But I still have my error.I've enabled the VT-x/AMD-x setting in virtual box also.

Do you have any idea about how to fix this error, or how to use an Android emulator ?

Comment: you have to download 64 bit images for android. Check in android sdk manager and download the appropriate image

Comment: @VivekMishra, In the SDK Manager I don't find anything to download refering 32 or 64 bit images for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find an answer to this problem, but continued to try different configs and parameters, and finally succeded with a **Nexus 5, Android 6.0** device with GenyMotion.

It seems to be impossible to launch Android custom device from GenyMotion with my config.

Effectivly, it is way more faster than with the Android Studio Virtual Devices.

Comment: I have an AMD processor and the arm image (especially for the newer SDKs such as lollipop) refuses to go past the ANDROID boot screen. I'm using Genymotion too!